# Difference between % vs * in string comparison in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

When trying to list down all tables names in a database having a specific name format, the following query works fine :

```
show tables like '*case*';
```

while the following does not

```
show tables like '%case%';
```

On the other hand, when comparing the actual data inside string columns its the vice-versa case

Working query :

```
select column from database.table where column like '%ABC%' limit 5;
```

Not working query :

```
select column from database.table where column like '*ABC*' limit 5;
```

What's the difference between the 2 operators * and % ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the difference between regular expressions and like patterns.

`LIKE` is built into the SQL language.  It has two wildcards:

- `%` represents any number of characters including zero.
- `_` represents exactly one character.

Regular expressions are much more flexible for matching almost any pattern in a string.

When SQL was invented, I don't think regular expressions were in common use in computer systems -- at the very least, the folks at IBM who worked on relational databases may not have been familiar with the folks at ATT who were inventing Unix.

Regular expressions are much more powerful than `LIKE` patterns, of course.  And Hive supports them via the `RLIKE` operator (and some other functions).

The `SHOW` functionality is not standard SQL.  So, the developers of Hive chose the more flexible method for pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

HiveQL attempts to mimic the SQL, but it does not strictly follow its standards.

The usage of the wildcards are not pertinent to the `LIKE` clause, but to the statement itself. [`SHOW`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Show) statements validate the wildcards based on the Java regular expression whereas when it comes to `SELECT` statements, Hive tries to stick with the SQL's wildcard validation.